# How to exclude an element with BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the article text from this article (https://www.vanityfair.com/style/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture) and exclude the legal container in the bottom. The text part seems easy, but can't seem to get rid of the container. I have separated it with the legal variable for easier use.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.vanityfair.com/style/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture'
r = requests.get(base_url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html)

legal = soup.find('div',{'class': 'legal-container'})

paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')

for text in paragraphs:
    print text.get_text()
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: Instead of excluding, can't you define a better selection than all `p` tags?

Comment: I tried that, however can't seem to find a good way. All of the text, including the text in the legal container has <p data-reactid="1", <p data-reactid="2"> etc tags. The legal container specifically is within <p data-reactid="553"> until <p data-reactid="566">; is there a good way to exlude those specifically or better define p tags?

Comment: How about the selector `div.article-main p`? All paragraphs in the article

Answer (score 5):

Always find the portion you want and see how you can extract that part alone, rather than getting all the text and then eliminating the unwanted ones.

In your case, the text you probably want are grouped in `section` tags within a `div` that has a `class` attribute of `content drop-cap`. You can get this using:

```
content_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'content drop-cap'})
```

This way, you get the flexibility of grouping the text by sections:

```
sections = content_div.findAll('section')
```

However, if you still insist on getting all the paragraphs and exclude the legal container specifically, you can remove the legal container from the `soup` object.

From [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose):

> **decompose()**
>
> Tag.decompose() removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys
>   it and its contents

If you choose to do this, then remove the tag(s) you don't want before extracting the text:

```
soup.find('div', {'class': 'legal-container'}).decompose()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's super useful! I'm still new to this :)